# How do I port Xcode storyboards to Android Studio?

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio, storyboard

Created prototype with code in Xcode and used Storyboards and a few ViewControllers. How can I port the design of those View Controllers directly onto Android Studio ViewControllers? Or do I have to re-create from scratch? Would the same .PNG files that I dropped into Xcode work for Android Studio?

Comment: I think that you'll have to import the project

Comment: Is it importable? From Xcode onto Android Studio? Have you done it successfully?

Comment: you have to go to **New--->Import project**

Answer (score 2):

A Storyboard is subjected to XCode and have nothing to do with Android studio. Till this date, there is nothing such mechanism which can port storyboard to Android Studio.